# Harming a nearly dead person

Tags: murder, accident

Bob is walking down the street when he slips on a banana peel. He bumps his head on the pavement and starts convulsing. Given the seriousness of his concussion, it seems that he's about to die.

Bob's ex girlfriend Alice happens to be walking nearby. She comes to his aid and gives him water. However, she secretly spikes the water with arsenic. Bob drinks the poisoned water and dies.

Is Alice guilty for Bob's death?

**Edit**: A similar question was asked [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30284/is-it-murder-to-kill-someone-whos-just-about-to-die). My question is a bit different since I'm asking whether it is legal to **harm**, and not *kill*, a person who is dying.

Comment: I'm the vignette above it's not clear whether it was Alice or the concussion that killed Bob.

Comment: Suggestion: pick a poison more likely to be a cause of death, given one swallowable dose. You could make it be a sedative whereupon he goes to sleep and dies because he didn't seek medical treatment.

Comment: Suggestion taken.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does he die from the poison or from the head injury?

If it's from the poison, yes, Alice is guilty of murder. If it's from the head injury, Alice is guilty of attempted murder.

If Bob dies from a combination of the head injury and the poison, Alice is likely guilty of murder. The general common law rule is that when there are two causes of death, liability attaches when the defendant's actions were a "substantial factor" in causing the death.

Comment: He dies from both.

Comment: You can't die twice, so you can't die from two totally different things. You might be dying from one and finally killed by another, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to die from a combination of two causes, neither of which would have been sufficient to cause death independently. *See, e.g.*, COVID-19.

Comment: Murder is not always instantaneous. It is possible to injure someone very severely, but they survive in hospital for a year and then die from their injuries; it’s still murder. In that year there is plenty of opportunity for someone to kill the helpless victim in hospital.

Comment: BDB-484: I’ve heard of a case where a dozen people beat up a man and he died, none of them individually did enough to cause death. That went down as murder and conspiracy to murder.

Comment: At the very least she would be guilty of attempted murder...

Comment: I love how I'm the only person instigating deeply philosophical legal debates here yet people downvoted my question three times!

Comment: I don't know that I'd call this a deeply philosophical legal debate. There's one answer and it's pretty well established.